# i have problem in VS code terminal to run npm command

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, npm-install

npm : The term 'npm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.

there is a error

Comment: Make sure that `npm` and `node` are install and are in your path so every new terminal can access to them. You can open a new terminal and check if they are install with these commands `npm -v` and `node --version`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem but as a solution, try running all npm commands in your cmd as an administrator, and you'd be fine.